# ASP.Net 404 Large XMLHttpRequest File Upload

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, iis

We have a web application which accepts a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest File Upload, it works correctly with files at ~25MB, testing with larger files at ~60MB this fails with a 404 status code, the .net application never intercepts the incoming POST request when at ~60MB so this leads me to believe IIS is stopping the incoming connection.

I have tried looking through logs but all I can see is that IIS receives the request (which is formed correctly) and its response code is 404.

Are there any IIS settings that need to increased to support this type of file upload scenario?

Our web.config contains the required element below to increase the upload limit and timeout. The 60MB file is within this size restriction and uploads well before 1 hour has passed. Also I would expect an ASP.Net exception page to appear but it never gets this far, just a 404.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="512000" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

The server is running windows 2012 Server and IIS 8.0.9200.16384

Answer (score 1):

Set the requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength in the ApplicationHost.config to a larger value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx