# Uploading a large file via Nancy ends in a 404

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, nancy

I'm experimenting with using Nancy framework and found it works quite simply and I got the methods for downloading & uploading files quickly. I even was able to download large files with no problem with no changes.

However, I am finding that when I upload a large file, I get a 404 error; Nancy's route is never reached nor does it shows in request tracing.

The same route works fine when I use a small file so I have to think there is something going below Nancy that prevents me from posting a large file. From past experience with WCF, it was necessary to set several parameters and I assumed most would not be even applicable in a Nancy framework, neither would I have any idea how to translate what I should do in WCF to what I should do in Nancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During typing up the question, I noticed a similar question here; [ASP.Net 404 Large XMLHttpRequest File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815332/asp-net-404-large-xmlhttprequest-file-upload)

From there, I derived that I needed to update my web.config in two places:

system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimit

system.web/httpRuntime/@maxRequestLength

With those 2 changes, the 404 turns into 200. So simple!